# stored procedure : update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

i'm novice in the stored procedure and this is my question:

I want to create a stored procedure to update rows in my table "F_COMPTET"

this is my code :

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[UpdateClt]
        @CT_Intitule    varchar(35),
        @CT_Contact     varchar(35),
        @CT_Adresse     varchar(35),
        @CT_Complement  varchar(35),
        @CT_CodePostal  varchar(35),
        @CT_Ville       varchar(35),
        @CT_CodeRegion  varchar(25),
        @CT_Pays        varchar(35),
        @N_Devise       smallint,
        @CT_Identifiant varchar(25),
        @CT_Siret       varchar(15),
        @N_CatCompta    smallint,
        @CT_Telephone   varchar(21),
        @CT_Telecopie   varchar(21),
        @CT_Email       varchar(69),
        @CT_Site        varchar(69),

    AS
    UPDATE [dbo].[F_COMPTET]
    SET

    [CT_Intitule]       = @CT_Intitule,
    [CT_Contact]        = @CT_Contact,
    [CT_Adresse]        = @CT_Adresse,
    [CT_Complement]     = @CT_Complement,
    [CT_CodePostal]     = @CT_CodePostal,
    [CT_Ville]          = @CT_Ville, 
    [CT_CodeRegion]     = @CT_CodeRegion,
    [CT_Pays]           = @CT_Pays, 
    [N_Devise]          = @N_Devise,
    [CT_Identifiant]    = @CT_Identifiant,
    [CT_Siret]          = @CT_Siret,
    [N_CatCompta]       = @N_CatCompta,
    [CT_Telephone]      = @CT_Telephone,
    [CT_Telecopie]      = @CT_Telecopie,
    [CT_Email]          = @CT_Email, 
    [CT_Site]           = @CT_Site, 


Where       [CT_Num] = @CT_Num,
```

---

and this is the problem that i got :

```
Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure UpdateClt, Ligne 20
Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'AS'.
Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure UpdateClt, Ligne 43
Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'Where'.
```

what do you think the problem is ?

Comment: remove comma(,) before as and where statement.

Comment: Error message in English: `"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, UpdateClt Procedure, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, UpdateClt Procedure, Line 43
Incorrect syntax near the 'Where' keyword."`

Comment: I think there are 2 commas, one in line `@CT_Site        varchar(69),` and one in line `Where       [CT_Num] = @CT_Num,`. Remove them and retry.

Answer (score 3):

Remove Last line comma and WHERE clause comma also :

Edit : Remove comma in Last paramter

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[UpdateClt]
    @CT_Intitule    varchar(35),
    @CT_Contact     varchar(35),
    @CT_Adresse     varchar(35),
    @CT_Complement  varchar(35),
    @CT_CodePostal  varchar(35),
    @CT_Ville       varchar(35),
    @CT_CodeRegion  varchar(25),
    @CT_Pays        varchar(35),
    @N_Devise       smallint,
    @CT_Identifiant varchar(25),
    @CT_Siret       varchar(15),
    @N_CatCompta    smallint,
    @CT_Telephone   varchar(21),
    @CT_Telecopie   varchar(21),
    @CT_Email       varchar(69),
    @CT_Site        varchar(69)
AS
BEGIN 
 UPDATE [dbo].[F_COMPTET]
 SET
[CT_Intitule]       = @CT_Intitule,
[CT_Contact]        = @CT_Contact,
[CT_Adresse]        = @CT_Adresse,
[CT_Complement]     = @CT_Complement,
[CT_CodePostal]     = @CT_CodePostal,
[CT_Ville]          = @CT_Ville, 
[CT_CodeRegion]     = @CT_CodeRegion,
[CT_Pays]           = @CT_Pays, 
[N_Devise]          = @N_Devise,
[CT_Identifiant]    = @CT_Identifiant,
[CT_Siret]          = @CT_Siret,
[N_CatCompta]       = @N_CatCompta,
[CT_Telephone]      = @CT_Telephone,
[CT_Telecopie]      = @CT_Telecopie,
[CT_Email]          = @CT_Email, 
[CT_Site]           = @CT_Site
WHERE [CT_Num] = @CT_Num
END
```

Comment: And the extra comma at the end of the last parameter.

Comment: Thant you so much broooo :D

Answer (score 0):

Check below :

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[UpdateClt]
        @CT_Intitule    varchar(35),
        @CT_Contact     varchar(35),
        @CT_Adresse     varchar(35),
        @CT_Complement  varchar(35),
        @CT_CodePostal  varchar(35),
        @CT_Ville       varchar(35),
        @CT_CodeRegion  varchar(25),
        @CT_Pays        varchar(35),
        @N_Devise       smallint,
        @CT_Identifiant varchar(25),
        @CT_Siret       varchar(15),
        @N_CatCompta    smallint,
        @CT_Telephone   varchar(21),
        @CT_Telecopie   varchar(21),
        @CT_Email       varchar(69),
        @CT_Site        varchar(69),
       @CT_Num         VARCHAR(60)
    AS
    BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[F_COMPTET]
    SET

    [CT_Intitule]       = @CT_Intitule,
    [CT_Contact]        = @CT_Contact,
    [CT_Adresse]        = @CT_Adresse,
    [CT_Complement]     = @CT_Complement,
    [CT_CodePostal]     = @CT_CodePostal,
    [CT_Ville]          = @CT_Ville, 
    [CT_CodeRegion]     = @CT_CodeRegion,
    [CT_Pays]           = @CT_Pays, 
    [N_Devise]          = @N_Devise,
    [CT_Identifiant]    = @CT_Identifiant,
    [CT_Siret]          = @CT_Siret,
    [N_CatCompta]       = @N_CatCompta,
    [CT_Telephone]      = @CT_Telephone,
    [CT_Telecopie]      = @CT_Telecopie,
    [CT_Email]          = @CT_Email, 
    [CT_Site]           = @CT_Site Where [CT_Num] = @CT_Num 

    END
```